# what is heroku used for?

Tags: python, heroku

I know this is really basic question, but I still have some confusion over what exactly heroku is meant for.  For example, if I create some simple python program that says "hello world" can I use heroku for that?

I've read several tutorials as well as herokus own website and still don't quite get it.  I think the descriptions are too dense for me.

Can some explain this in incredibly simple laymans terms?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly is Heroku?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008787/what-exactly-is-heroku)

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is a "platform as a service" that allows you to deploy web applications by simply pushing code to Heroku's repo. Heroku handles all the configuration and maintenance of the system for you. It's ideal for developers who just want to code, and not spend time having to set up and maintain servers.

Comment: Emphasis on "web applications". While you could write a hello world web app and put it on Heroku, Heroku is meant for more interactive uses.

Comment: I guess that's where my confusion was, as the Heroku website says you can use Python or Django, and I always thought of Django as like Python for websites or web applications?

Comment: Do you think it's possible to find something basic on github and deploy it through heroku for the sake of learning how heroku works?