# AWS AMI export to local Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I have got a running AMI Ubuntu instance with CI/CD pipeline with Jenkins,  Tomcat, Selenium, Sonar, Nagios etc .I have used elastic ip directly in different configuration to get it working.

Is there any easy and direct way to export this image to my local Ubuntu apart from   AWS export/import service.

Comment: What is the reason for down voting this question?Please mention the reason before down voting

Comment: StackOverflow is primary devoted to programming questions. Many people don't consider Cloud administration questions relevant.

Comment: agreed but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008787/what-exactly-is-heroku  this question what is heroku got 91 upvotes , there should be consistency , just because some one joined the forum earlier and had more reputation to down vote will make rookie like me stop asking questions ...

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth I don't agree with the down votes.  Cloud is fast becoming "infrastructure as code" and I place emphasis on the code aspect.  As the differences between programming and infrastructure management begin to fade (see FaaS - functions as a service) there needs to be room for having that conversation in this forum IMHO.

That said, let's move on to your questions.  AWS provides instance export functionality though this solution may not fit all use cases.  Two links below illustrate how to perform that export.  YMMV.  Good luck!

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-instance-export-task.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html